# Combine a background image and CSS3 gradients in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I want to combine background image and gradient. It should work in IE. my image is 3px width and 3px height. I am planning to give repeat for the background. How can we done it for Internet Explorer ???

Thanks in Advance

Comment: if you have  a tried code please share in jsfiddle

Comment: @fags wait i wil do this is in jsfiddle and share soon

Comment: Please specify which version(s) of IE you are targetting -- it makes a very big difference, particularly for things like this.

Comment: @fags  http://jsfiddle.net/r8SE7/  js fiddle

Comment: @Spudley i am targetting IE7 and ie8   fiddle is here jsfiddle.net/r8SE7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to target IE versions IE9 or earlier, they do not support CSS gradients.

There are work-arounds using `filter` and other hacks, but you will struggle to get those working if you want a background image as well.

My advice, therefore, is to use the [CSS3Pie](http://www.css3pie.com/) polyfill script. This library adds gradient support to older IE versions. It should be able to do what you want.

You'll end up with code like this in your CSS:

```
#myElement {
    background: url(bg-image.png) #CCC; /*non-CSS3 browsers will use this*/
    background: url(bg-image.png), -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#CCC) to(#EEE)); /*old webkit*/
    background: url(bg-image.png), -webkit-linear-gradient(#CCC, #EEE); /*new webkit*/
    background: url(bg-image.png), -moz-linear-gradient(#CCC, #EEE); /*gecko*/
    background: url(bg-image.png), -o-linear-gradient(#CCC, #EEE); /*opera 11.10+*/
    background: url(bg-image.png), linear-gradient(#CCC, #EEE); /*CSS3-compilant browsers*/
    -pie-background: url(bg-image.png), linear-gradient(#CCC, #EEE); /*PIE*/
    behavior: url(PIE.htc);
}
```

Please see the [CSS3Pie documentation](http://css3pie.com/documentation/supported-css3-features/) for further info.

Comment: can i give image in this section filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0, startColorstr='#e9e9e9', endColorstr='#ffffff' )
}

Comment: It looks like this: `filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(gradientType=0,startColorStr=#000000,endColorStr=#3d3c3c);`. However, as I said, watch out: it may not work properly, especially if you want to combine it with a background image as well. See also [lots of questions on SO about it](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=gradient+ie+filter)

Comment: Yep. Just stick it in your site root, and link to it in the `behavior` style, and then IE will recognise the `-pie-background` style and your gradients will work. Again, the pie docs page has more info if you need it.

Answer (score 1):

```
background: #6cab26;
background-image: url(IMAGE_URL); /* fallback */
background-image: url(IMAGE_URL), -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#444444), to(#999999)); /* Saf4+, Chrome */
background-image: url(IMAGE_URL), -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #444444, #999999); /* Chrome 10+, Saf5.1+ */
background-image: url(IMAGE_URL),    -moz-linear-gradient(top, #444444, #999999); /* FF3.6+ */
background-image: url(IMAGE_URL),     -ms-linear-gradient(top, #444444, #999999); /* IE10 */
background-image: url(IMAGE_URL),      -o-linear-gradient(top, #444444, #999999); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background-image: url(IMAGE_URL),         linear-gradient(top, #444444, #999999); /* W3C */
```

First 2 lines are the fallback for any browser that doesn't do gradients. See notes for stacking images only IE < 9 below.

Line 1 sets a flat background color.

Line 2 sets the background image fallback.

The rest set a background image and gradient for specific browsers.

Line 3 is for old webkit browsers.

Line 4 is for newer webkit browsers.

Line 5 is for Firefox 3.6 and up.

Line 6 is for Internet Explorer 10.

Line 7 is for Opera 11.10 and up.

Line 8 is what one day all the browsers will hopefully use.

See http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#layering for more information about it.

Also see http://css3please.com for cross-browser css3 templating. Currently it doesn't allow you to do multiple backgrounds with gradients, but it gives you the browser prefixes and is kept up to date.

Stacking images ONLY (no gradients in the declaration) For IE < 9

IE9 and up can stack images this same way. You could use this to create a gradient image for ie9, though personally, I wouldn't. However to be noted when using only images, ie < 9 will ignore the fallback statement and not show any image. This does not happen when a gradient is included. To use a single fallback image in this case I suggest using Paul Irish's wonderful Conditional HTML element along with your fallback code:

```
.lte9 #target{ background-image: url(IMAGE_URL); }
```

Comment: this works for IE 9 +. Ie <9 wont work, but you still can use the gradient using the Paul Irish's wonderful Conditional HTML element along with your fallback code(if you dont know what a fallback code is, visit http://nicolasgallagher.com/yet-another-html5-fallback-strategy-for-ie/:

** .lte9 #target{ background-image: url(IMAGE_URL); }  **

Comment: IE10 doesn't need the `-ms-` prefix (unless you're supporting the IE10 preview releases, but really there's no need to do that)

Comment: +1 vote for helping me, i found solution in Spudley Thanks Dude